# How do I upload a SwiftUI Image to my backend using Alamofire

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire

As the title states, I'm curious how I can upload my SwiftUI's Image to my backend using Alamofire. Every code example and tutorial I have run into relies on utilizing the UIImage but I'm working within SwiftUI it doesn't use UIImage.

Here is the function I found here ([upload image from multipart-from-data using Alamofire '~> 5.0.0-beta.3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278244/upload-image-from-multipart-from-data-using-alamofire-5-0-0-beta-3)) and am trying to get it work for my use case:

```swift
func uploadPhoto(
    url: String,
    image: Image,
    params: [String : Any],
    header: [String:String]) {


    let httpHeaders = HTTPHeaders(header)
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
        for p in params {
            multiPart.append("\(p.value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: p.key)
        }
       multiPart.append(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!, withName: "avatar", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    }, to: url, method: .post, headers: httpHeaders)
        .responseJSON{ response  in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let resut):
            print("upload success result: \(resut)")
        case .failure(let err):
            print("upload err: \(err)")
        }
    }
}
```

But the statement `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!` is giving me the error `Value of type 'Image' has no member 'jpegData'`.

A bit of research told me this is due to me trying to use SwiftUI's Image data type instead of UIKit's UIImage. I'd prefer to work within the Image data type due to things within my UI depending on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SwiftUI `Image` is-a view, and you need data. `UIImage` is-a data, so use it separately to be presented in `Image` and uploaded into database.

Here is an example (in pseudo-code):

```
struct ImageHolderView: View {
   let image: UIImage            // << data

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Image(uiImage: image)    // << present
         Button("Upload") {
           upload(to: url, data: image.jpegData)    // << upload
         }
      }
   }
}
```